# Airplay and repeatMode with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

I am unable to get airplay to repeat a video.

```
moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
[moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
```

This does not seem to work, it gets to the end of a video and airplay just stops. Does anyone know why, or how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a few apps with airplay and I didn't have to do anything fancy. 
However I enabled auto play. 
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

Try it maybe it solves your issue.